# Installing pandas without pip

Tags: pandas, pip

Is it possible to install pandas without installing pip or Is there any other way to use pandas without installing pip. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

pip is a package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python. Many packages can be found in the default source for packages and their dependencies

here is the another way:

Download and unzip the current pandapower distribution to your local hard drive.

Open a command prompt (e.g. Start–>cmd on Windows) and navigate to the folder that contains the setup.py file with the command cd

cd %path_to_pandapower%\pandapower-x.x.x\
Install pandapower by running

```
python setup.py install
```

[image: setup]

Comment: After this steps, how to import pandas!?

Answer (score -1):

You can get pandas installed using the Anaconda distribution, which includes the Anaconda prompt. After you open an anaconda prompt, you can run the following command:

```
conda install pandas
```

which will install the latest version of pandas, or:

```
conda install pandas=0.20.3
```

to get a specific version of the package. Another way to do it is to install it with Miniconda, which allows you to avoid downloading the Anaconda installer and hundreds of other packages. More information can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/install.html