# issue with installing pandas on python 3.9.6 windows visual studio code

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am using python 3.9.6 on windows
I am trying to install pandas through the terminal (Visual studio code)
by typing

```
pip install pandas
```

```
pip3 install pandas
```

```
pip3.9 install pandas
```

```
pip3.9.6 install pandas
```

All of them are returning an error
can anybody tell me what can I do please?

[image]

Comment: try :`python 3 -m pip install pandas`

Comment: also try `py -m pip install pandas`

Comment: Both returning same errors

Comment: Next time: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The errors in your image show that there is an issue with your Internet connection. It is likely you are behind a proxy. Try using a VPN as long as it won't get you in trouble (if you are at work or school?)

If you cannot connect to some other wifi or if you cannot fix the proxy if it resides on your local computer instead of being built into the router, try using this method to manually install pandas:

[Installing pandas without pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55256290/installing-pandas-without-pip)

[How to manually install a pypi module without pip/easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install)